# Does anyone know a free(trial) timestamp server service?

Tags: digital-signature, trusted-timestamp

Would like to know if anybody knows any free(trial) time-stamp server service.
I would like to test time stamping features in itext. Like I used Start Com class 1 as free CA for testing purposes. Hope I made it clear. Hoping someone knows a place
Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254394/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Like http://tsa.safecreative.org/ ?

Comment: great.... exactly what I wanted, plus i could certify. thanks a lot Konstantin !!

Comment: Let's move this to: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14139/trusted-timestamping-public-proof-that-i-knew-something-at-a-given-time-without

Comment: Somehow it doesn't seem right that this question was closed when it was so darn useful

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can try one of these publicly accessible RFC 3161 compliant time-stamping services:

1. https://freetsa.org
   Supports HTTP, HTTPS and TCP transports and has other features
2. http://time.certum.pl
3. http://zeitstempel.dfn.de
4. http://tsa.tecxoft.com
   Requires registration & paid
5. http://timestamp.sectigo.com
   (formerly http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161)
6. http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp
7. https://ca.signfiles.com/tsa/get.aspx
   Still active, but the configuration panel for the CA is wide open. I'd recommend against using it, as anyone can remove your access anytime.
8. https://tsp.iaik.tugraz.at/tsp/TspRequest
   Uses a test certificate.
9. http://timestamp.digicert.com
   Documentation (along with the certificate used, that changes every so often) is there : https://knowledge.digicert.com/general-information/rfc3161-compliant-time-stamp-authority-server

Timestamping services that went offline :

1. http://dse200.ncipher.com/TSS/HttpTspServer
2. http://tsa.safecreative.org
3. https://timestamp.geotrust.com/tsa
4. http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll
5. http://services.globaltrustfinder.com/adss/tsa

You can also try one of these publicly accessible RFC 3161 compliant client applications:

1. [TimeStampClient](https://github.com/disig/TimeStampClient)

Feel free to edit the answer and extend the list.

Comment: thanks jariq. #2 did the job, time stamp is embedded but could not be verified, but that was expected. thanks again !!!

Comment: I added one from symantec, not sure how that verification on timestamp works, but this one is verified, maybe because I own a symantec code signing certificate? This answer goes in-dept: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528456/verify-rfc-3161-trusted-timestamp

Comment: if you really do mean "Feel free to edit the answer and extend the list." then you should convert this answer into a community wiki. otherwise it's time consuming for us reviewers to to vet the suggested edit.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Thanks for the suggestion - I have converted answer to community wiki. I didn't know such option existed :)

Comment: Adding to this list, as the question is already closed: http://truetimestamp.org/

Comment: @Michael but truetimestamp.org seems not to be RFC 3161 compliant cryptographic service. It seems to be only online database of the hash values.

Comment: The timestamp provider http://tsa.safecreative.org uses certificates to sign the timestamps which uses a test CA as issuer. And that is not good at all.

Comment: I think we need to review the RFC, as I am really not confident with some of these alternate timestamp servers. After switching to a different one last build, I had, for the first time ever, an unsigned file get out. Now, that was probably my scripting, but I'm still looking into it. Does anyone know of a question already asks that clarifies this matter? I mean, are *any* good? And, if so, why not just create my own? So, I suspect there *are* limitations (OS support maybe), but I don't know.

Comment: Note that zeitstempel.dfn.de [does not permit commercial use](https://www.pki.dfn.de/zeitstempeldienst/).

Comment: Hi Guys, I am planning to use http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll for digital sign pdf on enterprise financial services. Is there any risk of data leakage?

Comment: A secret one used by google https://play.googleapis.com/play/log/timestamp

Comment: Symantec timestamping services are being shut down on October 31st, 2019 (so don't re-add their URLs!)

Comment: Another one to add that worked for me: http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticod

Comment: from Europa DSS you have a list of free TSP for testing purpose http://dss.nowina.lu/pki-factory/tsa/list

For example this one http://dss.nowina.lu/pki-factory/tsa/good-tsa