# How to Obtain a Digital Signiture for a Console Application?

Tags: c++, certificate, digital-signature, code-signing

I have made a simple console application to Play the Mario Theme Song in System Beeps. I am running Windows 7 and when the program runs it gives a warning that "Publisher is not verified". This happens as well on Windows 8 it says "Windows Smart screen prevented a unrecognized application from starting". How can I obtain a digital signature and link it to the console application so this error stops?

Source code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (392,100);Sleep(700);
    Beep (196,100);Sleep(700);
    Beep (262,300);Sleep(300);
    Beep (196,300);Sleep(300);
    Beep (164,300);Sleep(300);
    Beep (220,300);Sleep(100);
    Beep (246,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (233,200);
    Beep (220,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (196,100);Sleep(150);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(150);
    Beep (392,100);Sleep(150);
    Beep (440,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (349,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (392,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (294,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (247,100);Sleep(500);
    Beep (262,300);Sleep(300);
    Beep (196,300);Sleep(300);
    Beep (164,300);Sleep(300);
    Beep (220,300);Sleep(100);
    Beep (246,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (233,200);
    Beep (220,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (196,100);Sleep(150);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(150);
    Beep (392,100);Sleep(150);
    Beep (440,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (349,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (392,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (294,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (247,100);Sleep(900);
    Beep (392,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (370,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (349,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (311,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (207,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (220,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (220,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (294,100);Sleep(500);
    Beep (392,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (370,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (349,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (311,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (523,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (523,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (523,100);Sleep(1100);
    Beep (392,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (370,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (349,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (311,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (207,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (220,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (220,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (294,100);Sleep(500);
    Beep (311,300);Sleep(300);
    Beep (296,300);Sleep(300);
    Beep (262,300);Sleep(1300);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (294,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (330,200);Sleep(50);
    Beep (262,200);Sleep(50);
    Beep (220,200);Sleep(50);
    Beep (196,100);Sleep(700);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (294,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(700);
    Beep (440,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (392,100);Sleep(500);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (294,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (330,200);Sleep(50);
    Beep (262,200);Sleep(50);
    Beep (220,200);Sleep(50);
    Beep (196,100);Sleep(700);

    // Intro
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(100);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(300);
    Beep (392,100);Sleep(700);
    Beep (196,100);Sleep(700);
    Beep (196,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (330,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (392,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (523,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (660,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (784,100);Sleep(575);
    Beep (660,100);Sleep(575);
    Beep (207,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (262,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (311,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (415,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (523,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (622,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (830,100);Sleep(575);
    Beep (622,100);Sleep(575);
    Beep (233,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (294,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (349,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (466,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (587,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (698,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (932,100);Sleep(575);
    Beep (932,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (932,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (932,100);Sleep(125);
    Beep (1046,675);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

If the application is need to test it can be found here: [Mario System Beeps.exe](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xa51cnmveuzy2kc/AAB7CRTjHEAyaxeKzhmqTA5ja?dl=0)

Virus Scan(for all you PC Hypochondriacs): [Mario System Beeps.exe Virus Scan](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/ce75409f7f72314a767e295e6598688fd9a7d9cabeb2cc6a21d9e732877e0a04/analysis/1425440181/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign your application with a codesign certificate. Have a look at [this blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UsingCodeSigningCertificatesToSignDownloadedMSIsAndBuildReputationWithIE9SmartScreen.aspx) (from Hanselman) which explains how to do it. It isn't exactly for console applications but the principles are the same (sign with codesign and add a timestamp).

In most cases you need to buy the codesign certificate but there are CAs (i.e. if you are open source developer) where you can get it for free. One of them is Cetrum CA (which I am currently using). Take a look [here](https://www.certum.eu/certum/cert,offer_en_open_source_cs.xml). The process of obtaining it is a torture, but the certificate itself is OK. (it doesn't work with all browsers - use FF, single signon needs to be done on every page and mails are in Polish language.)

Timestamp can be obtained for free (i.e. from the link in Hanselmans blog or you can find a list of free RFC 3161 compliant timestamp authorities [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25053511/3245057))