# Passing username and password to CryptRetrieveTimeStamp function

Tags: c++, c, trusted-timestamp, wincrypt, rfc3161

I'm trying to retrieve a timestamp from a TSA using [CryptRetrieveTimeStamp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd433803(v=vs.85).aspx).

I can get it from some of the free services found on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25053511/76677), but always using the `TIMESTAMP_NO_AUTH_RETRIEVAL` flag.

But now that I want to use a paid service that uses credentials I cannot figure it out how to get it using a username and a password.

Does anyone know how to send a username and password to a TSA using CryptRetrieveTimeStamp?

Comment: Have you tried including it in the URL with `https://user:password@my.tsa.com/`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to do this myself, but have you tried putting them in the URL? Something like:

```
https://username:password@server.domain.com/ts/
```

I'd be curious to know if that works. Currently we're using free timestamping servers, but you never know.

By the way: I see you tagged your post with RFC 3161. Does that mean CryptRetrieveTimeStamp works with RFC 3161 timestamp servers? The documentation is marvelously unclear. I'm going to try it as soon as I get a chance, but it's always worth asking.

Comment: Yes, I've tried, but it didn't work.

And yes, CryptRetrieveTimeStamp works with RFC 3161. At least with most of the listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25053511/76677)